# Required field asterisk is not shown on the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code that generates a red asterisk in my required fields

```
.required:before {
    content:"* ";
    color:red;
}
```

in some it shows well but in others it doesn't

[image]

How can I make it show on the same line of my label?

```
<div class="form-group container-fluid">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label required">Nombre:</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="activity.name">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any chance of getting a snippet that reproduces this issue?  Otherwise it is going to be tough for anybody to provide you with any meaningful guidance...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's the width of your labels which pushes the text to lines below.
If you increase the width of `.control-label` you should be able to keep everything on the same line.

It looks like you are using bootstrap so try change the col widths (col-md-*)
you can try `col-md-3` and `col-md-9` or `col-md-4` and `col-md-8` respectively.

e.g. (3 and 9)

```
<div class="form-group container-fluid">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label required">Nombre:</label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="activity.name">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my mistake with this:

```
.required:before {
    content:"*\00a0";
    color:red;
}
```